# '/_CONTROLTEMPLATES/XXXX/XXX/XXX.ascx' does not exist

Tags: sharepoint-2013, web-parts, sharepoint-upgrade

I am new to Sharepoint.

I have a task of migration from 2010 to 2013.

Here are the steps I did:

1. Created a new webapplication.
2. Copied the DB from 2010
3. Restore on 2013.
4. Registered all Dll's for Webparts in GAC
5. Test-SPContentDatabase
6. Mount-SPContentDatabase.
7. Copied the Web.config safecontrol entries from 2010 to 2013 Web.config, (Note I have not upgraded yet).

When I try to browse site it gives me error and in the Log file I find this, please tell me what I need to do.

I dont have .wsp file etc, what has been provide to me all solution file (code of webparts etc)

```
file '/_CONTROLTEMPLATES/XXXX/XXX/XXX.ascx' does not exist.
    at System.Web.UI.Util.CheckVirtualFileExists(VirtualPath virtualPath)
    at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
    at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
    at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResult(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, ...    898fb39c-97ae-1037-0000-0dad08a25e2b
```

Comment: I fixed it by copying usercontrols provided to control template in 14 hive but after i upgrade will it work if i copy to 15 hive

Comment: It probably won't work on SharePoint 2013 if you copy it to 15 folder. The cause is that new controltemplates virtual path is '/_CONTROLTEMPLATES/15/xxx'. If your code refers old virtual path then you should copy control templates to 14 folder even on SharePoint 2013.